# Call a Django Rest Framework view within another Django Restframework view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've searched stack overflow and the internet for a solution to call a django restframework ListAPIView from anotehr django restframework APIView.

I've tried:

```
class ViewA(APIView):
   def get(request):
        response = ViewB.as_view({'get':'list'})(request)
        print response.render()
        # do other things with the response
```

However, I get the error:

```
    response = SubsidiariesStatisticsView.as_view({'get': 'list'})(request)
TypeError: as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

How do I pass in a request from viewA to viewB and get a response? 
Also, class `ViewB` has a `get_serializer_context` method. How do I call that from `ViewA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very nice practice, and also a overkill. instead just write a function that does what you want and use it in both views.

Comment: I think you're right. Will probably do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar case before and by following this [issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/933) from the official repo, changing my DRF `View` to `ViewSet` solved my problem. Just try modifying your views to extend from `ViewSet` or `GenericViewSet` or something.